# Can classification techniques used for identifying solids be used to identify precipitates?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

I am preparing for an assessed practical experiment where an unknown precipitate must be identified. I know that precipitates are insoluble, and my textbook says they are considered to be solid with reference to the aqueous solution.

I want to test for carbonate, halide, sulfate, and nitrate anions in the precipitate and understand that if it were a normal solid I would be able to test for carbonates by using a nitric acid solution, and test for halides by dissolving in nitric acid and testing with silver nitrate, and test for sulfates by dissolving the unknown solid in nitric acid and adding barium sulfate solution. I also know that I would normally be able to test for nitrates by heating the unknown solid with copper and then treating with H2SO4.

Are these classification techniques applicable to precipates as well?

Comment: You should first get some practical experience with these tests before you apply them on unknown samples.

Comment: "solid with reference to the aqueous solution"? What's that supposed to mean? Solids are solids that's it! Fresh precipitates tend to be easier to dissolve then compounds from shop, though. So slightly less aggressive treatment may be preferred.